# how to find number if ip addresses in a CIDR block

Tags: python

whats the best way to find total number of ip addresses in a cidr block using python

like if  input is  10.10.0.0/24

then the output should be 256

is there a way to do that with any modules in python like ipaddress?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ipaddress.ip_network()` function from `ipaddress` module:

```
import ipaddress

net = ipaddress.ip_network('10.10.0.0/24')
print(net.num_addresses)
```

The output:

```
256
```

`<'ipaddress.IPv4Network'>.num_addresses` property points to a total number of addresses in the network

https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.ip_network